# Are there any good Django plugins/modules for adding Server Sent Event support to your application?

Tags: django, server-sent-events

I've found this one: http://www.niwi.be/post/django-sse-html5-server-sent-events-django/ but it seems pretty rough around the edges and being at version 0.2 doesn't make me all that confident in it.

I know that SSE support isn't exactly rocket science so maybe it just isn't required but I thought I'd see if anyone else was aware of any other projects or modules that would help.

I'm looking for a commonly used module suggestion or a firm "just do it yourself" type of answer.

Comment: Just sayin', version numbers are not good indication about maturity. Long time ago version 1.0 meant "finished", nowadays for example newest stable Firefox is 11, and it's far from finished.

Comment: It's true.  I did also have a look at the implementation.  It's probably capable of what I'm looking to use it for, but also felt a bit awkward to use.  However I'm new to both Python and Django so I might be way off @Olli

Answer (score 0):

Sample Django SSE view:

```
class SSEView(View):
def  dispatch(self, request):
    response = http.StreamingHttpResponse(streaming_content=self.iterator(request=request), content_type="text/event-stream")
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    response['connection'] = 'keep-alive'
    return response

def iterator(self, request):
    """
    Yield unseen events (based on session timestamp)
    """
    user = request.user
    while True:
        user_ts = request.session.get("user_ts")    # Last seen
        sse = EVENT.find_one({
            "ts": {"$gt" : user_ts},                # New event, after last-seen
            "user_id": user._id},                   # Only requester's event
        })
        if not sse:
            time.sleep(random())
        else:
            yield sse
            request.session["user_ts"] = sse["ts"]  # Overwrite latest event time
```

Answer (score 0):

To support compression in SSE, you could add the Django decorator "gzip_page". See the following code example:

```
from django.views.decorators.gzip import gzip_page
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
...
class SSEView(View):
@method_decorator(gzip_page)
def  dispatch(self, request):
   pass
```

The reason of using the decorator is that the hop-by-hop HTTP header "Transfer-Encoding" is not allowed in Django.

You could use the header in other Python frameworks where the header is allowed.

```
response["Transfer-Encoding"] = "chunked"
```